# Work shifts into an Excel calendar

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar

I have a table that lists the start and end date of each shift an employee will be working throughout a year.

I'd like these shifts to show in a basic tabled calendar with dates listed in a column, with staff names across the top row. If a staff member is scheduled to work, an X should appear on their column against the date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated for this spreadsheet novice!

Thanks

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEl9q.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put this in F2, and copy and pasting across:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,"<="&$E2,$C$2:$C$7,">="&$E2, $A$2:$A$7,F$1)>0,"X","")
```

It is basically counting all occurrences where the calendar date (E2..) is between the first and last day, whilst also having staff equal to F1 or F2 or F3 etc.

Interestingly enough, if you use COUNTIF on its own, without the IF statement:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,"<="&$E2,$C$2:$C$7,">="&$E2, $A$2:$A$7,F$1)
```

It will put a "1" if someone has to work that day, but also put a 2 or 3 etc. if they have been accidentally allocated the same shift more than once.

Comment: Thanks mate, this works perfectly.